# Question about a definition

Tags: linear-algebra

There was a definition on my notebook. But sadly I cant read (...) part. What do we call $w_1,w_2,w_3...w_k$?

> Let V be a vector space on field F and $w_1,w_2, w_3..$ are subspaces
>   of V. for any i, $\alpha_i \in w_i, (i=1,...,k)$
>   if $\alpha_1=\alpha _2=\alpha _3...=0_v$  when $\alpha _1+\alpha _2+\alpha _3+...=0_v$; $w_1,w_2,w_3...w_k$ are called (...)

Comment: It looks like a mix between linear independence and direct sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the definition of direct sum, but messed up. Let me rewrite for you:

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$, and $W_1, \ldots, W_k$ subspaces of $V$. Suppose that for any collection $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k$ with $\alpha_i \in W_i$ for each $i$, we find that 
$$
\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \ldots + \alpha_k = 0_V
$$
implies that each $\alpha_i$ is zero. Then the subspaces $W_1$, $W_2$, are said to be "independent", and the set 
$$
W = \{ \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \ldots + \alpha_k | \alpha_i \in W_i \text{ for each $i$} \}
$$
is called the "direct sum" of $W_1, W_2, \ldots, W_k$. This direct sum is itself a vector subspace of $V$, and is the smallest subspace that contains all the $W_i$s (in the sense that any subspace $U$ that contains all of them also contains $W$).